# Double received unexpected message :get with ("url_here")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Whenever i do a RestClient.get or RestClient.post the tests fail with error:

> "Double received unexpected message :get with ("url_here")" 
>   and 
>   "Double received unexpected message :post with ("url_here")"
>   respectively.

These tests passed earlier but now all of them give the same error.

Here is how my test looks:

```
it 'connectivity test' do
  config.each do|env, values|
     response = RestClient.get values['url']
     expect(response.code).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

Please do let me know if you have any fix for this situation.

Thank you

Comment: Please, post your test & the code you're testing. Generally, you should add something like `allow(your_double).to receive(:get)` in your failing test, but it depends on implementation.

Comment: Modified my post to include my test. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any mentions of `RestClient` in the same spec file?

Comment: be careful, there is a problem with underscored models (like AdminUser which translate to a path like admin_user_path). Rails considers the underscore as a word delimiter and can't properly route. You can fix with config/initializers/inflections.rb (not sure at all if my coment is relevant though, I am not good with testing..)

Comment: For some files i have mentions of RestClient multiple times but for some it's just once. @nattfodd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like RestClient was being changed globally in some other test causing other tests to fail.

One of the tests was doing:

```
RestClient = double
```

changing that to the following solved the issue.

```
let(:RestClient) { double }
```